# SQL Group By only incude distinct entries not previously in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

I am using SQL server 2008. I have a Users table that holds users and their relationship to the Proposals in the system. Each user recorded is added to the system when a user is assigned to a Proposal. A User can show more than once in the Users table. The PK is User + Proposal. I have several columns, but the ones of interest are the `UserId`, `Proposal` and the `DateCreated`.  I'm trying to write a query against this table to show me how many Users were added per year. I'm using `group by  DATEPART(year, DateCreated)` but, of course, that will duplicate a User associated with a Proposal in a different year. Here's some data:

```
User    Proposal    DateCreated
user1   proposal1   1/1/2010
user2   proposal2   1/1/2010
user3   proposal2   1/1/2010
user4   proposal3   1/1/2010
user2   proposal4   1/1/2011
user5   proposal4   1/1/2011
user3   proposal5   1/1/2011
user6   proposal5   1/1/2011
user7   proposal6   1/1/2011
```

The result I am searching for is

```
NumUsersAdded       YearAdded
4                   2010
3                   2011
```

user1, 2, 3, 4 were added in 2010.  user5, 6, 7 were added in 2011.  The exclusion of user2 and user3 from the 2011 sum is what I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to select the minimal year for each user, and then count those:

```
SELECT   YearCreated, COUNT(*)
FROM     (SELECT    UserId, DATEPART(year, MIN(DateCreated)) AS YearCreated
          FROM      users
          GROUP BY  UserId) t
GROUP BY YearCreated
```

Comment: I like that, too.  I will try and swing back in a couple with comment

Comment: @Mureinik...accepting this answer since the performance is very fast.,  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is very straightforward, you just need to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR,DateCreated) YearAdded,
        COUNT(DISTINCT [User]) NumUsersAdded
FROM dbo.YourTable T
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable
                 WHERE [User] = T.[User]
                 AND DateCreated < T.DateCreated)
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR,DateCreated);
```

Comment: @Lamak...thanks for the feedback.  two edits to make this query work:  the Count(*) was modified to Count(Distinct UserId).  the > was changed to <.  I believe that got me the right resutl

Comment: @MikeTWebb yeah, of course it needed a `<`. I updated my answer